# How Do You Pass PropertyChanged Events Between Classes?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have been using data binding in WPF and I have been struggling with the following scenario:

If I have a class that is a Friend/Public property of another class, can I have that containing class notified when the property class's property changes?

I can get notifiers to work within the property class, or within the containing property if I reassign the property class, but I can't get this third way of event bubbling to work.

For example, the following trigger events are ones that I can get notifications of:

`myParentClass.child = myChild`

`child.childProperty = "A property"`

But I want to get a notification in `myParentClass` when:

`myParentClass.child.childProperty = "A property"`

From the following template example code:

```
Public Class cChildClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _childProperty As String
    Public Property childProperty As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Not _childProperty = value Then
                _childProperty = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("childProperty"))
            End If
        End Set
        Get
            Return _childProperty
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Class cParentClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _child As cChildClass
    Public Property child As cChildClass
        Set(ByVal value As cChildClass)
            _child = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("child"))
        End Set
        Get
            Return _child
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Declare `_child` as `WithEvents`, hook up a handler and it should work

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was close but was trying unsuccessfully with the public property. That does exactly what I was looking for. I've posted the complete example/answer below with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed answer, as per  Plutonix's suggestion:

In `cParentClass`, `Private _child As cChildClass` was changed to `Private WithEvents _child As cChildClass`.

Then I could call the private variable in the following function:

```
 Private Sub child_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles _child.PropertyChanged
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName & " has changed!")
 End Sub
```

The complete example, with the correction, is below:

```
Public Class cChildClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _childProperty As String
    Public Property childProperty As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Not _childProperty = value Then
                _childProperty = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("childProperty"))
            End If
        End Set
        Get
            Return _childProperty
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Class cParentClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private WithEvents _child As cChildClass
    Public Property child As cChildClass
        Set(ByVal value As cChildClass)
            _child = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("child"))
        End Set
        Get
            Return _child
        End Get
    End Property

    ....

    Private Sub child_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles _child.PropertyChanged
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName & " has changed!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private _child As cChildClass
    Public Property child As cChildClass
        Set(ByVal value As cChildClass)
            _child = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("child"))

            _child.PropertyChanged += Function(sender, e) 
                If e.PropertyName = "childProperty" Then
                '....WHEN EVENT CHANGED, YOU DO ANYTHING HERE
                End If    
            End Function
        End Set
        Get
            Return _child
        End Get
    End Property
```